# What is the need for a strong password?

Tags: security, web

Now a days each and every website recommend or force us to use a strong password. Every website is most likely that they hash the password and store it in their database then what is the need for strong password if they are hashing the password or why is it required in first place. Is it the same with salted hashing also?

Comment: It may sound like a problem caused by ever growing number of websites, requiring strong passwords, but there are plug ins and apps that generate strong passwords for you, based on the domain you try to access. Why bother remembering strong passwords? Let the scripts generate them for you, in every use.

Comment: Change your gmail password to "password" and see how long it takes to get hacked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because hackers try word lists and find out if they hash to the same value as stored in the database.

Weak passwords will be broken quickly, especially if no salt is used meaning that rainbow tables exist that allow lookups of the hash to find the password directly.

There is also the the threat of online attacks. e.g. an attacker trying every account against a web service login to see if they have `password1`, `abc123`, `baseball`, etc.

If you want a convenient way of having strong and unique passwords on every site you use, use something like https://lastpass.com

Answer (score 0):

The reason for a strong password is because simple passwords can be more easily "unhashed" than a strong one. The larger character sets used in the password, and the longer the password it is, the harder it is to crack. Take a look at these videos as there is way too much information to discuss here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7U-RbOKanYs

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3NjQ9b3pgIg

Comment: what about "salted hashing " in the video it is not explained. are those also easily cracked

Comment: I've never looked into salted hashing. The videos were to explain the reason for hashing passwords and the level of complexity you want in a password, not to go through all of the hashing techniques

Comment: I understand that but in case of a salted hashing is it required to have a strong password?. I wanted to know the theory.

Comment: yes the Salt help but it's not 100% perfect. Even with hashing and salt you need to have a strong password to ensure security against other attacks like the brute force.

Comment: @Sandeep: Passwords without a salt and be instantly broken by pre-computed rainbow tables. i.e. a lookup table that reverses hashes, because a hash for a particular password will always be the same. Adding a salt means that the same password hashed will be different every time. This prevents rainbow tables from being used, but a password guessing attack can still see if a particular password results in the hash. This slows down the attacker.